# Getting error while running in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, scikit-learn, jupyter

### ERROR

> Invalid parameter C for estimator
>   DecisionTreeClassifier(class_weight=None, criterion='gini',
>   max_depth=None,
>               max_features=None, max_leaf_nodes=None,
>               min_impurity_decrease=0.0, min_impurity_split=None,
>               min_samples_leaf=1, min_samples_split=2,
>               min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0, presort=False, random_state=None,
>               splitter='best'). Check the list of available parameters with `estimator.get_params().keys()`.

### ***CODE***

```
def train(X_train,y_train,X_test):
    # Scaling features
    X_train=preprocessing.scale(X_train)
    X_test=preprocessing.scale(X_test)

    Cs = 10.0 ** np.arange(-2,3,.5)
    gammas = 10.0 ** np.arange(-2,3,.5)
    param = [{'gamma': gammas, 'C': Cs}]
    skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5)
    skf.get_n_splits(X_train, y_train)
    cvk = skf
    classifier = DecisionTreeClassifier()
    clf = GridSearchCV(classifier,param_grid=param,cv=cvk)
    clf.fit(X_train,y_train)
    print("The best classifier is: ",clf.best_estimator_)
    clf.best_estimator_.fit(X_train,y_train)
    # Estimate score
    scores = model_selection.cross_val_score(clf.best_estimator_, X_train,y_train, cv=5)
    print (scores)
    print('Estimated score: %0.5f (+/- %0.5f)' % (scores.mean(), scores.std() / 2))
    title = 'Learning Curves (SVM, rbf kernel, $\gamma=%.6f$)' %clf.best_estimator_.gamma
    plot_learning_curve(clf.best_estimator_, title, X_train, y_train, cv=5)
    plt.show()
    # Predict class
    y_pred = clf.best_estimator_.predict(X_test)
    return y_test,y_pred
```

Answer (score 1):

<strike>It looks like you are making the `param` an array with a single dictionary inside. `param` needs to be just a dictionary:</strike>

**EDIT**:
Looking into this further, as mentioned by @DzDev, passing an array containing a single dictionary is also a valid way to pass in parameters.

It appears that your issue is that you are mixing the concepts of two different types of estimators. You are passing in the parameters for [svm.SVC](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html#sklearn.svm.SVC) but are sending in a [DecisionTreeClassifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html) estimator. So it turns out the error is exactly as it says, `'C'` is not a valid parameter. You should update to either using a `svm.SVC` estimator or updates your parameters to be correct for the `DecisionTreeClassifier`.

Comment: But In the doc (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html) it's mentioned that param_grid can bet : dict or list of dictionaries :/ ...